# Is it possible to make a telegram bot that could search through an google spreadsheet and return specific cell value?

Tags: excel, python-telegram-bot

So the idea is that the telegram bot would perform a similar function as the search function in google spreadsheet. I have researched on internet and couldnt find any tutorial or case on this. The scenario would be like:

telegram bot:
input /search 4Y123 (a room no.)

then telegram bot return the user of this room (e.g. IT department)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To improve your questions, please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Telegram bots call APIs using webhooks(HTTP request), you can do anything on the server end including searching data on spreadsheet